# Ошибка 'function' object is not iterable(Django)

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Хочу сделать простенькую страницу для постов, но выводит ошибку 'function' object is not iterable. Миграцию сделал. 
models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 120) 
post_body_news = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Articles
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path ( '', ListView.as_view( queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by( '-date' )[:20] ), views.post_news, name='post_news' )
```

]

posts.html

```
{% extends "news/wrepper.html"%}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <a href="/news/{{post.id}}"><h3>{{post.title}}</h3></a>
        <h5>{{post.date|date:'d-m-y'}}</h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def post_news(request):
    return render(request, 'news/post.html')
```

wrepper.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}>
    <title> News </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <a href="/">Главная страница</a>           
   </div>
<hr>
&copy; 
</body>
```

Comment: Вам надо определиться, какое представление вы хотите передать в `path` - `ListView` или `post_news`.

Comment: Подскажите как мне направить в папку templates с помощью LiastView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path ('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:20], template_name='news/post.html'), name='post_news')
```